# Adding a ribbon wrapper to twenty twelve theme

Tags: wordpress, css

I am trying to add a ribbon to the left of my page. I am using the great platform of word press. Specifically, the twenty-twelve template. I went into the code and edited under `themes/twentytwelve/style.css`  &  `themes/twentytwelve/header.php` . The problem is that it is showing on the right on just plain text. Css is not doing anything. Here is what i am trying to accomplish in wp theme: http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/9448/

**CSS for ribbon- themes/twentytwelve/style.css**

```
/*Ribbon Wrapper*/
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

**Header.php**

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">Welcome</div></div>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <hgroup>
            <img class="altlogo" src="http://www.theascp.org/wp-content/themes/ascpcics/images/ascpLogo.png" alt="" />

        </hgroup>

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
            <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
            <h1 class="site-title"><?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

        <?php $header_image = get_header_image();
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="main" class="wrapper">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared with the fiddle, there's no `.wrapper` rule in the CSS; but a link to the Wordpress version would help to see what's going wrong here.